# Integrating Liferay and Alfresco

Tags: liferay, alfresco

Im using Liferay version 5.2.3 and Alfresco Community Edition.I want to integrate Alfresco with Liferay . I want to show Alfresco as a portlet within Liferay.
Can someone please tell me how to go about doing this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple well-travelled links on the liferay community site.

The most often recommended is this one ...
http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Full+Integration+-+Liferay,+Alfresco,+SSO+and+LDAP

This one describes a more basic setup : 
http://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/integrating-alfresco-web-client-as-a-set-of-portlets-with-liferay

Answer (score 1):

Since CMIS was approved as a standard last month, the new best way to achieve this is probably via CMIS, as explained [here](http://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/integrating-alfresco-through-cmis-in-liferay).

Answer (score 1):

I used this one :

http://www.liferay.com/it/web/navin.agarwal11/blog/-/blogs/integration-with-alfresco-4-x-and-liferay-6-1

And this solution is still valid even with Alfresco 5